# No such module 'RxBlocking' in test target

Tags: ios, xcode, rx-swift, carthage, xcframework

I'm using Carthage for setting up my project's RxSwift dependency. And recently, I tried to use XCFrameworks instead with the command `carthage update --platform ios --use-xcframeworks`. I've set up all that is needed to be set (eg. changing the .frameworks to .xcframeworks in the `Link Binary With Libraries` in the targets' `Build Phase`, etc). It worked and I can run or test in the simulator, until today that is. When I was trying to do the tests this morning, all of a sudden it failed (although it worked fine before) with the error `No such module 'RxBlocking'`. I've double-checked it and the xcframework has already been built in the `Carthage/Build` folder, and the xcframework has already been added to the test target's settings.

I've tried all of these but it all failed:

1. Setting the `$(PROJECT_DIR)/Carthage/Build` to the `Framework Search Paths` for the target
2. Deleting `DerivedData/` and/or `Carthage/` folders
3. Resetting the Mac

Can anybody help me to fix this? BTW, I'm on XCode 12.4 and Swift 5. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually because of the Apple tools that can't search for the correct `Frameworks Search Path`. The fix is in this link: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/issues/2292#issuecomment-804045119